# .bashrc: in-script priority

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do two 'advanced' things with my bash prompt.

1. I want to show the status of my last command. I want to show my
2. current git branch (if I'm in a git repo)

I can do the two separately, and I can also do the ' then ', but I can not do ' then ' (which is what I would like).
When I do try to put the  before the  the status stops working, just stays in the same state no matter what the last command's status is. /:

I'm attaching my `.bashrc` below. As you can see, the last two line are the two possibilities. The one commented out is the one that doesn't work.

`.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

alias sublime="'/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'"
alias nano="sublime"
export EDITOR="sublime"


GREEN="\[\e[32;1m\]"
YELLOW="\[\e[33m\]"
RED="\[\e[31m\]"

DEFAULT="\[\e[0m\]"
BRACKETS=$GREEN
HAPPY=$YELLOW
SAD=$RED
BRANCH=$YELLOW


function parse_git_branch () {
       git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

SUCCESS_STR="\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo $HAPPY^_^$DEFAULT; else echo $SAD'O_o'$DEFAULT; fi\`"

# Nice looking bash prompt
PS1="\n$BRACKETS[$DEFAULT\u$BRACKETS]-[$DEFAULT\w$BRACKETS]\n$SUCCESS_STR$BRANCH\$(parse_git_branch) $ "
# PS1="\n$BRACKETS[$DEFAULT\u$BRACKETS]-[$DEFAULT\w$BRANCH\$(parse_git_branch)$BRACKETS]\n$SUCCESS_STR $ "
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first point, that's what I does on all my *nixes.

Put this in you `~/.bashrc` (simplified PS1 to avoid noise ):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=$(
    cat<<-'EOF'

    _temp_var=$val_ret _pipe_status="${PIPESTATUS[@]}"

    if((val_ret == 0)); then
        _temp_var=$(( $(tr -s " " "+" <<< "$_pipe_status") ))
    else
        _temp_var=$val_ret
    fi

    if((_temp_var == 0)); then
        PS1="\u@\h:\w$"
    else
        PS1="\u@\h:\w|ERROR:$_temp_var|$"
    fi
    EOF
)
```

See what it does :

[image: prompt]

From `man bash`:

> PROMPT_COMMAND
>
> If set, the value is executed as a command prior to issuing each primary prompt.

Comment: Now, you can modify the prompt with your `git` repository obviously.

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. You can 'accept' the reply too by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackoverflow website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackoverflow works, thanks ;)